# Command prompt color changes on completion suggestions in zsh/oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I have a problem that I couldn't find a solution to (maybe I'm just a horrible google user).

Anyways: I use oh-my-zsh with a custom theme and one or two plugins, but nothing too fancy. Whenever I double-press tab to bring up the completion suggestions, e.g. when using cd, my prompt's automatically colored blue (see attached image).

I have tried deactivating my theme and some stuff in ~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/completion.sh, but I couldn't find anything that helps. I just want my regular green even though I double tab.

Any help?

[image: Example of coloring]

Comment: Could you post the plugins you are using and the theme so we can reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This answer to a related question seems to address your issue (I have not tested it myself):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/is-there-a-way-to-set-coloring-for-cd-tab-complete/16245#16245

Comment: If it addresses the issue, then the question can be closed as a duplicate. If it does not, then this answer is just wrong. Either way, you shouldn't simply post links to other questions as answers.